# Disable/Enable specific div id (class) in html

Tags: html

How to remove/append specific div inside html code? I have one way script...

```
<body>

  <div id = "GFG_DIV"> 
    This is Div box. 
  </div> 

  <button onClick = "GFG_Fun()"> 
    click here 
  </button> 

  <!-- Script to remove HTML element -->
  <script> 
  var div = document.getElementById('GFG_DIV');  

  function GFG_Fun() { 
    div.parentNode.appendChild(div); 
  }     
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify what you want exactly. But with the given information, you probably want to something like below.

### Example: Toggling a CSS class

You can access CSS classes of an element by accessing the property `classList` of an element. Then, you can toggle a class (add it, if it's not there, remove it, if it's there).

```js
function gfg_fun() {
   var div = document.getElementById('GFG_DIV');
   div.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <div>
   <div id="GFG_DIV">GFG_DIV</div>
   <button onclick="gfg_fun()">
     click here 
   </button>
 </div>
```

### Example: Toggling an element

You could also add the whole element and remove it again from the DOM on a click.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerText = 'a div element.';
var shown = false;

function gfg_fun() {
  if (shown) {
    parent.removeChild(div);
  } else {
    parent.appendChild(div);
  }
  shown = !shown;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <button onclick="gfg_fun()">
     click here 
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Not work. Okey. I have div element which should be removed/add from html code on click. Now it's only remove.

Comment: I've changed the solution.

Comment: Thx!!!!!! It's working now. ))) Maybe you now how to do it with resize window. Disable in mobile version (specific width in css)

Comment: I would just add a media query to your CSS styles. For example: `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { #specialdiv { display: none; } }` and add an element `<div id="specialdiv"></div>`. It will be shown when the browser is wider than 600px.

Comment: Ok. About above solution. It didn't work as I intended. I have div in specific place of html and need that it disable it. But you solution add/remove div not container (for example by ID)

Comment: @Alex You could upvote or accept the answers which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do this task easily. Below are few resources important for you to do this.

[Jquery Append](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp)

[Append ()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

[Jquery Remove](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_remove.asp)

[Remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

For further information refer those.

Comment: Please do not propose a jQuery solution if the asker does not explicitly want a solution with jQuery. I don't think that it's appropriate to recommend jQuery in 2020.

Comment: Why do you say so?

Comment: jQuery was, initially, when it was created in 2006 very valuable, because the web interfaces of the browsers at that time were very diverging and clumsy. The web, however, evolved and with this, core elements of jQuery were added as default browser functions (e.g. `querySelector()`, `fetch`, etc.). So, jQuery is not really necessary anymore in 2020. Many companies are still using it though, but to propose a solution relying on the extra step of adding an external, unnecessary and unasked for library like jQuery, is not very helpful in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner too, so hope this helps!

1. It's important to include a type in every button
2. It's bad practice to use 'click here' as action text - best not get into that habit, even when playing around like this ;)
3. You need to append an element to something in DOM already

This code will add one div on click (https://codepen.io/grace-snow/pen/VwLrKVN):

```
<!-- html -->
<div id="GFG_div">
  <p>Paragraph in existing div</p>
</div>
<button type="button" onClick = "GFG_Fun()"> 
   Add a div 
</button> 

<!-- Script to add HTML element -->
<script> 
  const oldDiv = document.querySelector('#GFG_div');
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');  

function GFG_Fun() {
  oldDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
  console.log('div added!');
}
</script>
```